# VS Code intellisense crossing some CSS properties

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, css-grid

Look at the `grid-row-gap` property:

[image]

Why does VS Code show some elements with a cross, like `grid-row-gap` in this image? I have to use it, but its effects won't show.

I want to use the properties `grid-row-gap` and `grid-column-gap`, but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

Being crossed out indicates – from context – that the property is no longer to be used.

In the case of `grid-row-gap` this is because the property-name now has the `grid` prefix removed, in order to allow the same property to be used with CSS flexbox layout, instead of necessitating a `flex-row-gap` equivalent. That being said:

| old name: | equivalent: |
| --- | --- |
| grid-column-gap | [row-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-gap) |
| grid-row-gap | [column-gap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/row-gap) |

Incidentally, if you'd entered that option into the document, and then hovered over it, you would have seen the message:

> Property is obsolete. Avoid using it.
>
> Specifies the gutters between grid rows. Replaced by 'row-gap' property.
>
> (Firefox 52, Chrome 57, Safari 10, Opera 44)